# Exported terraform path (~/.profile) is not working properly

Tags: macos, terraform

I am attempting to install terraform and export the path in my `~/.profile` and it does not seem t be doing anything as is get the following message when trying to run terraform:

```
terraform -version
-bash: terraform: command not found
```

My `~/,profile` entry looks like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/usr/local/terraform"
```

NOTE: this is from a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks weird for me about the path, should it be `/usr/local/bin/terraform` ?

anyway, copy the line to ~/.bash_profile. stop and start your xterm, then try again.